# Why do Data.Binary instances of bytestring add the length of the bytestring as prefix

Tags: haskell, bytestring

Looking at the `put` instances of the various ByteString types we find that the length of the bytestring is always prefixed in the binary file before writing it. For example here - https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.8.0/docs/src/Data.Binary.Class.html#put

Taking an example

```
instance Binary B.ByteString where
    put bs = put (B.length bs) -- Why this??
             <> putByteString bs
    get    = get >>= getByteString
```

Is there any particular reason for doing this? And is the only way to write Bytestring without prefixing the length - creating our own newtype wrapper and having an instance for Binary?

Comment: If you later would read the `ByteString` back, and after the `ByteString`, there is extra data (like an `Int`, etc.). How would you know where it ends?

Comment: Hmm, I am dealing with an immutable file whose format already contains various clues about the size of the data that follow. I am not sure I understand when you say "if there is extra data" because I will be dealing with something immutable.

Comment: take for example `put some_bytestring >> put 'A'`, if you later want to retrieve it back, so with something like `(get :: Get ByteString) >> (get :: Char)`, how will the reader know `'A'` is not part of the bytestring?

Comment: You can use `putByteString bs` to avoid the length prefix. When reading back the file, you will have to recover how many bytes to read from your other fields in your file.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any particular reason for doing this?

The idea of `get` and `put` is that you can combine several objects. For example you can write:

```
write_func :: ByteString -> Char -> Put
write_func some_bytestring some_char = do
    put some_bytestring
    put some_char
```

then you want to define a function that can read the data back, and evidently you want the two functions to act together as an identity function: that if the writer writes a certain `ByteString` and a certain `Char`, then you want the read function to read the same `ByteString` and character.

The reader function should look similar to:

```
read_fun :: Get (ByteString, Char)
read_fun = do
    bs <- get
    c <- get
    return (bs, c)
```

but the problem is, when does a `ByteString` ends? The `'A'` character could also be part of the `ByteString`. You thus need to somehow indicate where the `ByteString` ends. This can be done by saving the length, or some marker at the end. In case of a marker, you will need to "escape" the bytestring, such that it can not contain the marker itself.

But you thus need some mechanism to specify that when the `ByteString` ends.

> And is the only way to write `Bytestring` without prefixing the length - creating our own newtype wrapper and having an instance for `Binary`?

No, in fact it is already in the `instance` definition. If you want to write a `ByteString` without length, then you can use [**`putByteString :: ByteString -> Put`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.10.0.0/docs/Data-Binary-Put.html#v:putByteString):

```
write_func :: ByteString -> Char -> Put
write_func some_bytestring some_char = do
    putByteString some_bytestring
    put some_char
```

but when *reading* the `ByteString` back, you will need to figure out how many bytes you have to read.